# Why doesn't control pass to the next instruction after I call a DLL function?

Tags: delphi, dll

I have this function :

```
procedure call_dll(path:string);
var
  lib: HMODULE;
  mainfn: procedure(); stdcall;
begin
if FileExists(path) then
 begin
 lib := LoadLibrary(PAnsiChar(path));
 Win32Check(lib <> 0);
 try
   @mainfn := GetProcAddress(lib, 'main');
   Win32Check(Assigned(mainfn));
   mainfn();
 finally
   FreeLibrary(lib);
 end;
 end;
end;
```

this is a function to call a DLL and call a function named `main()` it works fine but after finish executing the `main()` function the process still working and using 13.4% from the Processor.

This is when I've call it

```
showmessage('Test message 1');
call_dll('Test.dll');
showmessage('Test message 2');
```

After executing I see the message "Test message 1" and then the message from the DLL function but it still there and do not pass to the third showmessage instruction . **Please I need help**

Comment: Are you sure it's 13.4% and not 12.5%? The latter would represent 100% usage from one of your eight CPU cores.

Comment: The problem was in some instructions in the DLL  (between 13.1% and 13.5% :) )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
showmessage('Test message 2');
```

This message does not show. Which means that this code is never reached. The only reasonable conclusion is that

```
mainfn();
```

is called but never returns. That is, execution descends into the DLL but never returns to the caller.

The answer to your problem is to be found in your DLL.